# Possible to check file size of multiple S3 keys?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using the following code to check individual file sizes, which works fine:

```
s3.headObject({ Bucket: myBucket, Key: myKey }, (err, data) => {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else console.log(data);
});
```

To check multiple files I can easily write the above code into a loop, but I'm hoping there is a way that only involves a single s3 operation. I know that when I want to delete multiple files, I can send params like this:

```
params = { 
  Bucket: myBucket, 
  Delete: { 
    Objects: [
      { Key: 'some-key-1' },
      { Key: 'some-key-2' },
      { Key: 'some-key-3' }
    ]
  }
}

s3.deleteObjects(params, ...etc)
```

Is such a thing possible with the headObject operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the listobjectsv2 api instead of the headObject api?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjectsV2-property

Answer (score 0):

P.S. I wrote this handy async recursive function to deal with the 1000 object limit:

```
function storageAudit(params, callback, size = 0) {
  s3.listObjectsV2(params, (err, data) => {
    for (object of data.Contents) size += object.Size
    if (data.NextContinuationToken) {
      params.ContinuationToken = data.NextContinuationToken;
      storageAudit(params, callback, size);
    } else callback(size);
  });
}
```